# Javascript Connect 4 Minimax and Alpha-Beta Pruning not working

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, p5.js, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am attempting to program Connect 4, using a minimax AI algorithm and alpha-beta pruning. This is the entire code, but the three functions where I believe the problem may lie in are `bestMove()`, `minimax()`, and `useHeuristic()`. I apologize in advance if it is not easily readable.

```
let board = [
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty'],
  ['empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty', 'empty']
];

// Initializing drawing variables

let holeDiameter = 60;
let holeRadius = holeDiameter / 2;
let xBorder = 15;
let yBorder = 10;

let isMouseMoved = false;

// Available spots

let available = [];


// Initializing the players

let ai = 'red';
let human = 'yellow';
let currentPlayer = human;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(540, 430);
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      available.push(board[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

function equals4(a, b, c, d) {
  return (a == b && b == c && c == d && (a != 'empty'));
}

function equals3(a, b, c) {
  return (a == b && b == c && (a != 'empty'));
}

function equals2(a, b) {
  return (a == b && (a != 'empty'));
}

function checkWinner() {

  let aiFours = checkFours(ai);
  let humanFours = checkFours(human);

  // tracks available spots

  let openSpots = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] == 'empty') {
        openSpots++;
      }
    }
  }

  if (aiFours > 0) {
    return ai;
  } else if (humanFours > 0) {
    return human;
  } else if (openSpots == 0) {
    return 'tie';
  }

}

function checkFours(player) {

  let numOfFours = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

      if ((i < 4) && equals4(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j], board[i + 2][j], board[i + 3][j]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfFours++;

        // vertical checking

      } else if ((j < 3) && equals4(board[i][j], board[i][j + 1], board[i][j + 2], board[i][j + 3]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfFours++

        // diagonal 1 checking

      } else if ((i < 4) && (j < 3) && equals4(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j + 1], board[i + 2][j + 2], board[i + 3][j + 3]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfFours++;

        // diagonal 2 checking

      } else if ((i > 2) && (j < 3) && equals4(board[i][j], board[i - 1][j + 1], board[i - 2][j + 2], board[i - 3][j + 3]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfFours++

      }
    }
  }
  return numOfFours;

}

function checkThrees(player) {

  let numOfThrees = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

      if ((i < 5) && equals3(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j], board[i + 2][j]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfThrees++;

        // vertical checking

      } else if ((j < 4) && equals3(board[i][j], board[i][j + 1], board[i][j + 2]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfThrees++

        // diagonal 1 checking

      } else if ((i < 5) && (j < 4) && equals3(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j + 1], board[i + 2][j + 2]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfThrees++;

        // diagonal 2 checking

      } else if ((i > 1) && (j < 4) && equals3(board[i][j], board[i - 1][j + 1], board[i - 2][j + 2]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfThrees++

      }
    }
  }
  return numOfThrees;
}

function checkTwos(player) {

  let numOfTwos = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

      if ((i < 6) && equals2(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfTwos++;

        // vertical checking

      } else if ((j < 5) && equals2(board[i][j], board[i][j + 1]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfTwos++

        // diagonal 1 checking

      } else if ((i < 6) && (j < 5) && equals2(board[i][j], board[i + 1][j + 1]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfTwos++;

        // diagonal 2 checking

      } else if ((i > 0) && (j < 5) && equals2(board[i][j], board[i - 1][j + 1]) && board[i][j] == player) {

        numOfTwos++

      }
    }
  }
  return numOfTwos;
}


function nextSpace(i) {
  let col = i;
  for (let j = 5; j >= 0; j--) {
    if (board[col][j] == 'empty') {
      return j;
    }
  }
}

function aiMove() {
  let row = floor(random(1) * 7);
  board[row][nextSpace(row)] = ai;
  currentPlayer = human;
}

function bestMove() {
  let bestScore = -Infinity;
  let move = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) { //let j = nextSpace(i);

      if (nextSpace(i) == j) {

      if (checkTwos(human) == 0 && checkTwos(ai) == 0) {
        let col = floor(random(1) * 7);
        let row = nextSpace(col);

        move = [col, row];
      } else {
        board[i][nextSpace(i)] = ai;
        let score = minimax(board, 5, -Infinity, Infinity, false);

        board[i][nextSpace(i) + 1] = 'empty';

        if (score > bestScore) {
          bestScore = score;
          move = [
            i,
            j
          ];
        }

      }
      }
    }
  }

  board[move[0]][nextSpace(move[0])] = ai;
  currentPlayer = human;
}

let scores = {
  red: +100000,
  yellow: -100000,
  tie: 0
}

function useHeuristic() {

  let aiFours = checkFours(ai);
  let humanFours = checkFours(human);

  let aiThrees = checkThrees(ai) * 1000;
  let humanThrees = checkThrees(human) * 1000;

  let aiTwos = checkTwos(ai) * 10;
  let humanTwos = checkTwos(human) * 10;

  if (aiFours > 0) {
    return 100000;
  }

  if (humanFours > 0) {
    return -100000;
  }

  let heuristicScore = aiThrees + aiTwos - humanThrees - humanTwos;

  console.log('heuristicScore: ' + heuristicScore);
  return heuristicScore;
}

function minimax(board, depth, alpha, beta, isMaximizing) {
  let result = checkWinner();

  if (result != null) {
    return scores[result];
  }

  if (depth == 0) {
    let eval = useHeuristic();

    return eval;
  }

  if (isMaximizing) {

    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (nextSpace(i) == j) {
          board[i][j] = ai;
          let score = minimax(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, false);
          board[i][j] = 'empty';
          bestScore = max(score, bestScore);
          alpha = max(alpha, score);
          if (beta <= alpha) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return bestScore;
  } else {

    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (nextSpace(i) == j) {
          board[i][j] = human;
          let score = minimax(board, depth - 1, alpha, beta, true);
          board[i][j] = 'empty';
          bestScore = min(score, bestScore);
          beta = min(beta, score);
          if (beta <= alpha) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return bestScore;
  }
}

function mouseMoved() {

  isMouseMoved = true;

}

function mousePressed() {

  // Drop piece for human player

  if (currentPlayer == human) {
    let i = floor(abs(((mouseX + 30) - 3 * xBorder) / (xBorder + holeDiameter)));

    board[i][nextSpace(i)] = human;
    currentPlayer = ai;
    setTimeout(bestMove, 500);
  }

  // Remove taken spots from available

  for (let i = 0; i < available.length; i++) {
    if (available[i] !== '') {
      available.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}


function draw() {

  // Board background drawing

  background(0, 150, 255);

  for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {

      // Draw the holes

      let holeX = (i + 3) * xBorder + ((2 * i)) * holeRadius;
      let holeY = (j + 4) * yBorder + ((2 * j)) * holeRadius;

      fill(color(255, 255, 255));
      noStroke();
      ellipse(holeX, holeY, holeDiameter);

      // Pieces

      let spot = board[i][j];

      if (spot == ai) {
        fill(color(255, 0, 0));
        ellipse(holeX, holeY, holeDiameter);
      } else if (spot == human) {
        fill(color(255, 255, 0));
        ellipse(holeX, holeY, holeDiameter);
      }
    }
  }

  if (isMouseMoved) {
    let i = floor(abs(((mouseX + 30) - 3 * xBorder) / (xBorder + holeDiameter)));

    let j = nextSpace(i);

    noFill();
    stroke(color(255, 255, 0));
    strokeWeight(10);

    ellipse((i + 3) * xBorder + ((2 * i)) * holeRadius, (j + 4) * yBorder + ((2 * j)) * holeRadius, 60);
  }
  // Recording Result of Game

  let result = checkWinner();
  if (result != null) {
    console.log(result);
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**
When I run the code and it is the AI's turn, two things happen. It thinks for a while, slowing down my browser, and then it gives me one of two errors. Either it says that my code has an infinite recursion problem, or it says 'move' on line 235 is undefined (the second to last line of `bestMove()`).

**Things I have tried:** I have tried logging many items to the console, including depth in `minimax()` (to make sure the program reaches a depth of 0), the heuristic score at the end of `useHeuristic()` (to make sure it uses the heuristic), and move at the end of `bestMove()` (to see if it is actually undefined, which it apparently is).

Also, just to clarify, at first I was receiving the infinite recursion error, but afterwards it switched to the move is undefined error, without me making any code changes. I find this very odd, and I really hope someone can help me. Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I changed the second line of `bestMove()` to this:
`let move = [];`, which seems to have fixed both the infinite recursion error I did some more tinkering and figured out that the program thinks `move[0]`, in the second to last line of `bestMove()` is undefined. I am not sure why that is.

**Link to Sketch:** https://editor.p5js.org/aaravshah18/sketches/KDAykjkZY

Comment: How are these methods: `round()`, `abs()`, `random()`, `floor()`, etc. functioning without the `Math` object?

Comment: I wrote this code in an online editor called p5.js, which I suppose has built in functions so I don't need the Math object for that.

Comment: Remove one of those tags and replace it with [p5.js] tag.

Comment: Ok. Do you have any idea what can fix my problem with my code?

Comment: Could you share the sketch in the online editor? That way we can try to recreate the problem. It sounds like your hitting an indefinite loop..
When i copy this code into the editor and run it i get an error "
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined (sketch: line 188)" which is totaly different than what you experienced...

Comment: Yes. Sorry I am new to using this platform, do you want me to send a link to the sketch?

Comment: Hey, i see you got it to work now, does it not? :) very nice! It is strange move[0] = undefined. Since you only put the i and j in there..

Comment: Yes, thank you! I forgot to update this post. I got it working because I noticed a small error in the minimax function, when it is the minimizing player's turn. I had set bestScore to -Infinity, when it should actually have been +Infinity.